# SubForm Control Reflects Null when Display says it is not

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, subform

Running into a weird issue and am having problems troubleshooting the issue.

Details:

1 -

```
? Forms![Form]![Subform].Form.Control
```

prints a value of "Null" in the immediate window when the sub form via the UI clearly shows a value. This value is part of the data source of the subform ( as in it is not altered or input by the user, even though edits are allowed) and is loaded with this value preset. Further more, validations occur in the subform that fire correctly that check this value.

2-

```
Me.Requery
Me.SubForm.Form.Requery
```

These do not fix the issue.

3-

This seems to be sporadically occurring and does not happen all the time. I can not get it to happen again on my box (at all, windows 7) and it seems to happen to one specific person (windows 10 tablet) every time.

4 -

I changed the value of the control in question once on my box and the issue hasn't happened since. This is kind of a hassle for end users who have metrics to meet.

5-

sadly this is Access 97 :'(

Would anyone like to give me more troubleshooting ideas? I am going to have that user try it on a different box to see if this solves the issue and maybe its how the OS is interacting with Access.

Comment: I agree with ashlee that it is a bit clearer if you use something like `? Forms![myForm]![mySubformControl].Form.myTextbox` if you don't want to give the actual names. -- Perhaps appending `.Value` might help with the problem (although it should be the default property).

Comment: Sorry I thought that was acceptable since most documentation I find presents it in that fashion. Even in the Allen Browne chart she copy and pasted the presentation is quite similar. And yes I did try .value (and it is supposed to be the default property). Unfortunately it isnt helping me track down the unpredictability of the issue. I might rebuild the form from the ground up and see if there are corruption issues.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information for a solid answer, partly because how to refer to a control, varies depending on *where* you are referring to it ***from***, and it sometimes makes a different *why* you are referring to it.  (

Also, more representative examples than you've provided would be helpful.

For example, I assume (and *hope*!) that your form is not called `Form` and your control is not called `Control`.  When including examples it's important to make sure, while keeping it short, that it still representative of what you're actually having the problem with.

[This page has a helpful chart](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) to which you can compare the several difference ways to refer to a control:   (<sub>Click to expand</sub>)

[image: img]

---

If this doesn't help you solve your problem, consider adding code and/or screenshots to your question.

Comment: Obviously my forms arent called Form/SubForm and the control is obviously not called control. The line i sued to refer to a subform's control is the correct way to call it (which is why I used the specific string of text). Adding code isnt going to solve the issue or help alleviate/explain why the control is representing null when 1) the UI display a value and 2) the record in the database has a value. I dont know how more explicit I can be without actually screen capping the immediate window and the form itself and even then it still doesnt add anything more to the discussion.

Comment: Also having screen shots might not explain why the issue persists for some people but not others. This excludes the possibility for corruption (i think) and makes me think it could be OS related but Im not sure how or why that might be (if it is in fact the case)